# Django ORM ExtractDay / ExtractHour / ExtractMinute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to do a GROUP BY to a queryset. I'd like to group the datetimes. So I'm using the function Extract.

My model is the following:

```
class CustomData(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(CustomModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'custom_data'
```

And this is my QUERY:

```
    from django.db.models.functions import (Extract, ExtractDay, ExtractHour, 
        ExtractMinute, ExtractMonth, ExtractQuarter, ExtractSecond, ExtractWeek, 
        ExtractWeekDay, ExtractYear
    )

    cd = CustomData.objects.filter(site=c).order_by('-id')

    cd = cd.annotate(
        year=ExtractYear('created'),
        month=ExtractMonth('created'),
        day=ExtractDay('created'),
        hour=ExtractHour('created'),
        minute=ExtractMinute('created'),
    ).values(
        'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute'
    )

    cd = cd.annotate(number=Max('number'))

    for x in cd:
        print(x)
```

But the result is the following:

```
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 15}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 17}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 28}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 97}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 11}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 19}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 7}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 8}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 12}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 15}
{'hour': None, 'minute': None, 'day': None, 'year': None, 'month': None, 'number': 41}
```

All the time fields are None. Any know know what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Probably `created` is null for all records? Check it with `CustomData.objects.values('created')`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner The "created" fields are not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You've marked the `created` field as a nullable field. Make sure that it is not `NULL`:

```
queryset = CustomData.objects.filter(created__isnull=False)
```

Consider accessing year, month, hour, and other parts of the date directly. This way you don't need to use the `Extract{part}` functions:

```
x = queryset.last()
print(x.created.year, x.created.month, x.created.day, x.created.second)
```

Also, it's possible to use date parts when forming a queryset:

```
x = queryset.filter(created__year='2016').last()
```